# Populate jQuery object with each function in switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I need structure like this:-**

```
var input = ["meal_1" : ["name": "Apple",
                           "Id": "5"],//and so on
             "meal_2" : ["name":"Cat",
                           "Id":"3"],
             "meal_3" : ["name":"Coffee"]//and so on
        ];
```

I'm getting the information from elements and creating array, in which i `.push()` all text from the elements in. There is how it looks like:

```js
 var meal_number = $('.cd-meal-number').find(':selected').data('id');
 var meal_array = [];
 
  switch(meal_number){
    case 1:
//взимаме цялата информация за елемент и тн. за сесията



$('.cd-food-meal-container[data-meal_number="1"]').find('.cd-added-food').each(function(){
  var food_name = $(this).find('#cd-food-name').text();
  var food_state = $(this).find('.cd-food-state').text();
  var food_image = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
  var food_carbs = $(this).find('.cd-carbs').text();
  var food_prots = $(this).find('.cd-prots').text();
  var food_fats = $(this).find('.cd-fats').text();
  var food_kkals = $(this).find('.cd-kkals').text();
  meal_array['meal_1'] = meal_array.push({"food_name":food_name,"food_state":food_state,"food_image":food_image,"food_carbs":food_carbs,"food_prots":food_prots,"food_fats":food_fats,'food_kkals':food_kkals});
                                console.log(meal_array);
                            });

                
                break;
                case 2:
$('.cd-food-meal-container[data-meal_number="2"]').find('.cd-added-food').each(function(){
  var food_name = $(this).find('#cd-food-name').text();
  var food_state = $(this).find('.cd-food-state').text();
  var food_image = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
  var food_carbs = $(this).find('.cd-carbs').text();
  var food_prots = $(this).find('.cd-prots').text();
  var food_fats = $(this).find('.cd-fats').text();
  var food_kkals = $(this).find('.cd-kkals').text();
  meal_array['meal_2'] = meal_array.push({"food_name":food_name,"food_state":food_state,"food_image":food_image,"food_carbs":food_carbs,"food_prots":food_prots,"food_fats":food_fats,'food_kkals':food_kkals});
                                console.log(meal_array);
                            });

                break;
                case 3:
                   // and again and again
                break;
```

```html
<div class = 'cd-added-food' data-meal_food_id = "1">
                <div class = 'cd-food-name'><span id = 'cd-food-name'>Orange</span><span class = "cd-food-state">Peeled</span><i><img class = "cd_clear" src = '/uploads/images/delete_icon.png'/></i></div>
                <img src = 'src'/>
                <div class = 'cd-stats'>
                    <table class = 'cd-table'>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Въглехидрат</th>
                            <th>Протеин</th>
                            <th>Мазнини</th>
                            <th>Калории</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class = 'cd-carbs'>20</td>
                            <td class = 'cd-prots'>10</td>
                            <td class = 'cd-fats'>5</td>
                            <td class = 'cd-kkals'>140</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            
<select class="cd-meal-number">
            <option data-id="1">Първо Хранене</option>
            <option data-id="2">Второ Хранене</option>
            <option data-id="3">Трето Хранене</option>
            <option data-id="4">Четвърто Хранене</option>
            <option data-id="5">Пето Хранене</option>
            <option data-id="6">Шесто Хранене</option>
            <option data-id="7">Седмо Хранене</option>
            <option data-id="8">Осмо Хранене</option>
        </select>
```

This is my structure, and it is working, but the problem is there that when i run the script(which is on click) it is populating the array with the `$.each()`, which is only in `case 1:` for example, and when i choose meal 2 and run the script, the array from meal_1 is deleted and meal_2 is replacing it.

I need the array to be populated by all meals, when user clicks, do not need them to replace each other. Sorry for long code, I am trying to give you maximum information.

Thank you !

Comment: _"I need structure like this"_ - The "structure" is invalid syntax.

Comment: Yep, not exactly like it I'm just giving a representation of how it should look.Pretty confused by reading for objects,mapping,arrays for this problem which i got, and decided to ask here.